# How to install new ts library for old js library

Tags: typescript

I need to use **qs** typescript library however when i install it it's js i tried npm ***install --save @types/qs***

However it still wont recognize when i import qs from 'qs' but it still wont work , is there any solution for me?

I thought it would overwrite the qs package in node_modules but in there is still the index.js file
Is there any solution for me?

```js
import FormData from 'form-data';
// var axios = require('axios');
import axios from 'axios';
// var qs = require('qs');
import  qs from 'qs'// error here
var fs = require('fs');//?
var mime = require('mime-types');//?
var path = require('path');//?
const readChunk = require('read-chunk');//?
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```js
{
  "files": [],
  
  
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ],
  "include": [
    "index.d.ts"   // declaration file path
  ],

  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
       "./*"
      ]
     },
     "noImplicitAny": false

   }
  
}
```

Comment: `@types/qs` does _not_ replace files in `node_modules/qs`. It is installed in `node_modules/@types/qs`. The TypeScript compiler loads what is in that `node_modules/@types` folder by default, but that may be affected by the `tsconfig.json`. Sharing its content may help.

Comment: Yes sir, I added the tsconfig file to the post